# How to install PostgreSQL 13 in Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, 19.10, 19.04, postgresql, database

How to install PostgreSQL-13 in Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Which release?  You've tagged two.

Answer (score 16):

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'

wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update

# Specify/replace the version number you want to install

sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-13
```

Comment: Not sure why I couldn't find this answer anywhere else but this worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

> If the version included in your version of Ubuntu is not the one you
> want, you can use the PostgreSQL Apt Repository. This repository will
> integrate with your normal systems and patch management, and provide
> automatic updates for all supported versions of PostgreSQL throughout
> the support lifetime of PostgreSQL.
>
> The PostgreSQL Apt Repository supports the current LTS versions of 18.04 & 16.04
>
> on the following architectures: amd64 i386 ppc64el
>
> While not fully supported, the packages often work on other non-LTS versions as
> well, by using the closest LTS version available. To use the apt
> repository, follow these steps:
>
> Create the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list and add a line for
> the repository

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ YOUR_UBUNTU_DISTRIB_CODENAME_HERE-pgdg main
```

> Import the repository signing key, and update the package lists

```
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

From https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of postgresql-client and postgresql-11 in the Ubuntu 19.04 and 19.10 default repositories is version 11. To install these packages run:

```
sudo apt install postgresql-client postgresql-11
```

The latest version of postgresql-client and postgresql-*XX* in the Ubuntu 20.04 default repositories is version 12.

```
sudo apt install postgresql-client-12 postgresql-12
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and paste:

```
sudo apt install postgresql-12
```

Then check the status:

```
sudo systemctl status postgresql
```

[image]

Comment: Tried this. I get an error: `E: Unable to locate package postgresql-12`

Comment: nope, not working: `E: Unable to locate package postgresql-12`

Comment: You need to add the repository before this `wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -` then update
`sudo apt-get update` and then install it